# Where do I include normalize.css?

Tags: css

Should I include it first or last among my CSS files? I'm not sure.

What's the general practice with things such as CSS resets / normalizers ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FIRST. Respect the cascade. Normalize is a starting point, then your css can add to those attributes. Thats' the cascade.

Answer (score 10):

You would include it first. For optimal response you should do the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
<!-- Add additional stylesheets next -->
```

This allows the *normalized* stylesheet to take effect with your other stylesheets cascading off of it.

Answer (score 4):

> Approach 1: use normalize.css as a starting point for your own
>   project’s base CSS, customising the values to match the design’s
>   requirements.
>
> Approach 2: include normalize.css untouched and build upon it,
>   overriding the defaults later in your CSS if necessary.

**[Reference](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have included normalize css in your package.json with npm then you can import it in your js file like so,

```
import 'normalize.css';
```